# Function to generate substrings from a string with some characters replaced

Tags: python, string, recursion

I have a string with length n. For example:

```
s = "gcgcagagacgcaagcctaRgggSgggggttgggggggcgtgt"
```

I want a substring from it:

```
s1 = s[0:20]
```

Result:

```
s1 = "gcgcagagacgcaagcctaR"
```

Then check if it has any characters that are not "a", "c", "g" or "t". This is true for s1, as it ends with an "R".

Next step is to replace the "R" with "A" and "G" (or "S" with "C" and "G"), that is, create two new strings:

```
"gcgcagagacgcaagcctaA"
"gcgcagagacgcaagcctaG"
```

Then take a new substring of s:

```
s1 = s[1:21]
```

Repeat this until I've reached the end of the original string. In this example that would be:

```
s1 = s[23:43]
```

If there's two special characters in the substring, it would result in 4 new strings generated. If three then 8 and so on. If zero special characters, then print the substring as is and move ahead.
There are more special characters than in the example, but the point remains the same.

What I have so far:

```
def generate_substrings(sequence, start, end):
    codes = set("MRWSYKVHDB")
    s = sequence[start:end]
    start += 1
    end += 1

    if end > len(sequence):
        return

    elif not any((nt in codes) for nt in s):
        print(s)

    else:
        for i, nt in enumerate(s):
            if nt not in "acgt":
                if nt == "R":
                    s = s.replace("R", "A")
                    print(s)
                    return generate_substrings(sequence, start, end)
                    s = s.replace("R", "G")
                    return generate_substrings(sequence, start, end)
                elif nt == "S":
                    s = s.replace("S", "C")
                    return generate_substrings(sequence, start, end)
                    s = s.replace("S", "G")
                    return generate_substrings(sequence, start, end)

generate_substrings("gcgcagagacgcaagcctaRgggSgggggttgggggggcgtgt", 0, 20)
```

I know that this script does not do what I need, but it's what I have at the moment and I would be really grateful if someone can help me expand (or rewrite) it.

Comment: your function is not recursive

Comment: @LonGdueZBOO I think that's more constructive for OP to explain _why_ you consider this function not recursive

Comment: This function doesnt call itself, so it is not recursive.

Comment: only 1 return is possible

Comment: @LonGdueZBOO I appreciate the input, but it would be infinitely better if it'd be anything constructive.

Comment: If you put two sequential return, only the first one will be called.

Comment: Why the regex tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def generate_substrings(sequence):
    length = len(sequence)
    for i in range(len(sequence)- 19):
        currentSequence = sequence[i:i+20]
        recursiveReplaceLetter(currentSequence)

def recursiveReplaceLetter(s):
    isOk = True
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if (s[i] == "R"):
            isOk = False
            newSequence1 = s
            newSequence1 = newSequence1[:i+1].replace("R", "A") + newSequence1[i+1:]
            recursiveReplaceLetter(newSequence1)

            newSequence2 = s
            newSequence2 = newSequence2[:i+1].replace("R", "G") + newSequence2[i+1:]
            recursiveReplaceLetter(newSequence2)
            break

        elif(s[i] == "S"):
            isOk = False
            newSequence1 = s
            newSequence1 = newSequence1[:i+1].replace("S", "C") + newSequence1[i+1:]
            recursiveReplaceLetter(newSequence1)

            newSequence2 = s
            newSequence2 = newSequence2[:i+1].replace("S", "G") + newSequence2[i+1:]
            recursiveReplaceLetter(newSequence2)
            break


    if (isOk):
        print (s)

sequence="gRRcagagacgcaagcctaRgggSgggggttgggggggcgtgt"
generate_substrings(sequence)
```